# Neo4j - How to create a nested object with a tree structure

Tags: neo4j

I have a tree structure with access rights on each node of my tree, I would like to get only the nodes I have access to in a nested object like this:

```
{
  name: "project 1",
  Children: [
   {name: "nested child"}
  ]
}
```

this is my graph structure:

[image]

I want to get all nodes that `Marion` has a `:VIEWER` relation with, this is the query I tried but I don't have the nested structure

```
MATCH path =(a:Account {firstName: "Marion"})-[:VIEWER]->()
WITH collect(path) AS paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths)
YIELD value
RETURN value;
```

I get this structure

```
{
  "firstName": "Marion",
  "viewer": [
    {
      "_type": "Project",
      "name": "project 1",
      "_id": 1,
      "type": "project"
    },
    {
      "_type": "Child",
      "name": "nested child",
      "_id": 4,
      "type": "child"
    }
  ],
  "_type": "Account",
  "_id": 29,
}
```

`nested child` should be in `project1` in a `children` object

There is no limit to the depth of parent -> children relationship

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

If ever you have a better idea for my graph structure i am open to optimization

> EDIT

Thanks to your answers it works, but i would like to add some params

There can be other type of relations not only `:VIEWER` there can be  `:VIEWER :EDITOR :OWNER`

and i need to know what relation `Marion` as with each node

I have made this query but i don't understand why me result is split in to tables ?

```
MATCH (c)<-[:IS_PARENT_OF*]-(p)
WHERE (p)<-[:VIEWER | EDITOR]-(a)
// collect the child nodes per project
WITH TYPE(r) as relation, p,collect(distinct c) AS children
// return a map that contains project and children names
RETURN {name: p.name, Children: [c in children | {name: c.name, access:relation}]}
```

> RESULT

```
{
  "name": "project 1",
  "Children": [
    {
      "access": "EDITOR",
      "name": "Experimental design"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "name": "project 1",
  "Children": [
    {
      "access": "VIEWER",
      "name": "nested child"
    }
  ]
}
```

> EXPECTED

```
{
  "name": "project 1",
  "Children": [
 {
      "access": "EDITOR",
      "name": "Experimental design"
    },
    {
      "access": "VIEWER",
      "name": "nested child"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume the project nodes have a different label than the child nodes as per your node visualization.

I would try the following:

```
// get the top-level project
MATCH (a:Account {firstName: "Marion"})-[:VIEWER]->(p:Project)
// get the child nodes
MATCH (p)-[:IS_PARENT_OF*]->(child)
WHERE (child)<-[:VIEWER]-(a)
// collect the child nodes per project
WITH p, collect(distinct child) AS children
// return a map that contains project and children names
RETURN {name: p.name, Children: [c in children | {name: c.name}]}
```

Edit:

Added the answer by Hakan

```
// get the children
MATCH (a:Account {firstName: "Marion"})-[:VIEWER]->(child:Child) 
// get the parent project that is also viewable 
MATCH (p)-[:IS_PARENT_OF*]->(child) 
WHERE (p)<-[:VIEWER]-(a) 
// collect the child nodes per project 
WITH p, collect(distinct child) AS children 
// return a map that contains project and children names 
RETURN {name: p.name, Children: [c in children | {name: c.name}]}
```

Comment: In addition, it is most likely more performant to query in the opposite direction, match child first, and then check what project the child belongs to. Since there is only one path from the child to the project, where as from the project to the child there are many paths but only one that is the "right path".

Comment: @Tomaž Bratanič in the first `MATCH` we get the `Project` nodes but a `Child` node could be the root of the structure, how could i change the query to check for `Project and Child` 

Second question, how could i add the type of relation  `Marion` has with each node in the return object like this :` {name: c.name, access: <relation type>}`

Comment: @Håkan Löfqvist
Thank you for your comment it is a good idea, i understand what you mean but how would you make it?

Comment: In the first MATCH, just match for Marion is viewer of child. Then swap in the where clause to check that Marion is also viewer of project.

Comment: // get the children
MATCH (a:Account {firstName: "Marion"})-[:VIEWER]->(child:Child)
// get the parent project that is also viewable
MATCH (p)-[:IS_PARENT_OF*]->(child)
WHERE (p)<-[:VIEWER]-(a)
// collect the child nodes per project
WITH p, collect(distinct child) AS children
// return a map that contains project and children names
RETURN {name: p.name, Children: [c in children | {name: c.name}]}

Comment: Maybe @Tomaž Bratanič can update the answer to hold both alternatives.